# Where condition in KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am looking for help with Kusto query:

```
| where test == "Jump" and Time > 2
| where test == "Run" and Time > 20
| where test == "Stand" and Time > 5
```

It is interesting because I am not getting error message, however I should get results...
At least I get results when I run where commands separately, but when I execute query as one, no results...any idea why?

```
Test    Time

Jump     10
Run      13
Stand    15
Jump     5
Run      15
Stand    4
```

Answer (score 3):

The query you included is the equivalent of:

```
...
| where test == "Jump" and Time > 2
    and test == "Run" and Time > 20
    and test == "Stand" and Time > 5
| ...
```

In the data set you've provided, the intersection (`and`) of all of the conditions you included is empty, therefore no records are returned:

- `| where test == "Jump" and Time > 2`: 2 matching records are (`Jump`, `10`), (`Jump`, `5`)
- `| where test == "Run" and Time > 20`: there are no matching records.
- `| where test == "Stand" and Time > 5`: 1 matching record is (`Stand`, `15`)

I *think* your intention was to use the `or` keyword, e.g.:

```
...
| where (test == "Jump" and Time > 2)
     or (test == "Run" and Time > 20)
     or (test == "Stand" and Time > 5)
| ...
```

Otherwise, you'll need to clarify what the expected output is.